# Button of 2nd form submits 1st form that doesn't have a submit button

Tags: javascript, forms

I have 2 forms on one page.

Form 1

```
<form id="form1" method="get" action="action1.php">
  <input type="text" id="input1">
</form>
```

This form is submitted by:

```
$('#input1').on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    $('#form1').submit();
  }
});
```

as I don't want a submit button on this form.

The 2nd form:

```
<form id="form2" method="post" action="action2.php">
  <input type="text" id="input2">
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Now if I press the button on the 2nd form, it submits the 1st form. Not sure why that happens as the submit button is inside the second `<form>` tag.

Also; as form 1 will be on many pages (it's a search bar in a navigation bar) I'd like to 'future proof' this so that I don't run into problems in the future when I place multiple forms on a page. Ideally that would mean that this issue is fixed by changing form 1.

**Update**

Stupid mistake...! I had `$('form:first').submit();` on the `<button type="submit">Save</button>` somewhere else in my code, so the first form got submitted...

Comment: @JoSSte what would that change???

Comment: Normally an input field in a form submits default on enter anyway.

Comment: There is something else going on. A form plugin or something. A button inside a form is default the submit button for the form unless it is type="button"

Comment: Try opening the developer console. pause script execution, press the button and step through what is happening...

Comment: It was my own stupid mistake, see updated answer. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Something else is going on.

try hitting enter in these two fields - you will see there is no need for script

```js
$("form").on("submit",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.id + " submitted");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" method="get" action="action1.php">
  <input type="text" id="input1"> Submits on enter
</form>
<hr/>
<form id="form2" method="post" action="action2.php">
  <input type="text" id="input2"> Submits on enter or on click
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It was my own stupid mistake, see updated answer. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

make this change in form 2

```html
<form id="form1" method="get" action="action1.php">
  <input type="text" id="input1">
</form>
    
<form id="form2" method="post" action="action2.php">
  <input type="text" id="input2">
  <button type="submit" form="form2">Save</button>
</form>
```

[read this to know more about form attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_form.asp)

Comment: _"The id of the <form> of which the input is a member; if absent, the input is a member of the nearest containing form, or is not a member of a form at all"_ - try the snippet in my answer. You will see it works fine without the attribute

Comment: Apologies for not stating that ideally this would be supported cross browser, or at least modern browsers, but this solution would not work in MS Edge as per your link.

Comment: It was my own stupid mistake, see updated answer. Sorry!

Comment: As I guessed. Please delete the question